# Install, configure, and connect to s git server

Tags: git, connection, installation, config

I'm beginner in git world, i want to install a git server for managing projects.
i have ubuntu 14.04 installed on a machine server. 
I found this tutorial : https://www.vultr.com/docs/setting-up-git-on-ubuntu-14-04. The installation was OK.
Now : 
1 - I search how i can connect to my repository to upload my projects.
2 - I search the config for connecting from eclipse.

thanks for help.

Comment: Write down what issues you are facing or where you are stuck.

Comment: the commands that i have extecuted are :  
apt-get install git
git config --global user.name "User User"
git config --global user.email "user@gmail.com"
mkdir ~/projects
cd ~/projects
git init
mkdir ~/project1
cd ~/project1
git init

at this level, it  is OK

My problem, is i have no idea how i can connect to my server for cloning project1 ?

Answer (score 0):

So you have installed "git" which provides you to have a complete version control system on your machine. You can create/track branches/tags etc.

Now, when you say "clone", git clones a "remote" repository to your "local" machine. For that, you'll need either HTTP or SSH url of this remotely hosted git repo, such as on Github/Gitlab/Bitbucket etc.

If you just want to clone a local repo on local machine,

```
$ git clone /path/to/repo
```

[Cloning Git repository locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941090/cloning-git-repository-locally)

If you want to clone local repo to a remote server, check this out : [git clone from local to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142936/git-clone-from-local-to-remote)

Do check out a Github tutorial : https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/